# How to use annotation to Manage get and set properties

Tags: c#, annotations

I want to use annotation to map class attributes with sql columns, then I made this code, but I don't know if this is correct, I want to add a dictionary item using as key the name used in annotation, but I don't know if the following code is the quickest way to do that, for example, there is a way to get the property inside that property without specifying this in string? (this.GetType().GetProperty("Id")

```
public class Key : Attribute {
            public string Key { get; set; }

            public Key(string key) {
                Key = key;
            }
    }
```

-

```
public class Example {

        public IDictionary<string, object> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        [Key("id")]
        public Guid Id {
            get { return (Guid) Attributes[((KeyName)this.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Guid), true).First()).Key]; } 
            set { Attributes.Add(((KeyName)this.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Guid), true).First()).Key, value); }
        }

}
```

Comment: If you want a class to be generated from a Database Setup, Entitify Framework is usually the droid you are looking for.

Comment: you can use nameof(Example.Id) instead of "id"